# Can 'although' and 'even if' both be correct in the following sentence?

Tags: coordinating-conjunctions

Which one do you think is more appropriate in the following sentence? I feel 'even if' sounds better to me. But I am not sure.

1. I take the dog for a walk every day *even if* sometimes it is raining.
2. I take the dog for a walk every day *although* sometimes it is raining.

Thanks.

Comment: Or ***...but** sometimes it's raining,* which is closer to ***although*** in nuance. Or ***However...*** (which for some reason works better if it starts a new sentence).

Comment: I'd say (1) would sound natural only after say [A] "I never take my little  Poochy out in bad weather." ... [B] "I take the dog for a walk every day even if sometimes it _is_  raining." // (1' ) "I take the dog for a walk every day, come rain come shine" sounds more natural as a standalonesentence.

Comment: The first sentence could be true even if it never rains at the speaker's location. The second sentence couldn't.

Comment: It is the word *sometimes* that redunds the *even though* and *although*. Even though and yet then but sometimes I make up words, I still gotta take the dog out or else.

Answer (score 2):

As far as the grammatical correctness goes for the two sentences that you've mentioned, they are both right. But if you mean to ask if they are both semantically equivalent and interchangeable, that's a no.

The dependent clause of the first sentence "even if sometimes it is raining" serves to emphasise on the first part of the sentence, "I take the dog for a walk every day". It reinforces the idea that whether it rains or not, the dog is taken out for a walk.

In the second sentence, however, "although" is helping  point out an exception. That sentence may connote (aside from other possible meanings) that the dog is taken out for a walk on all days except on days when it rains. If you may be having difficulty in understanding how this may be so, try appending a little more context to that sentence. Consider this:

> I take the dog for a walk every day although sometimes it is raining. On such days, we spend the day at home playing fetch.

However, there can be no way wherein the first sentence can be made to highlight an exception.

[edits: improvement in clarity, omission of 'but' in accordance with [LPH's comment]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/590162/can-although-and-even-if-both-be-correct-in-the-following-sentence/590165?noredirect=1#comment1481325_590165)

Comment: You're saying the second sentence implies the speaker doesn't take the dog out every day? I'm not sure that's true. Certainly "I walk the dog every day although sometimes we don't go very far" implies you go out every day.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't very clear. I meant to highlight the difference in usage. I was trying to point out that *although* in a sentence like this **can** mean that I don't take the dog out every day, whereas *even if* could never. The part of the sentence followed by an although serves to point out an exception (works as a but). Even in your sentence, the exception highlighted is that you don't go very far some days.

Comment: "But" is used for the expression of a contrast whereas "although" is used for concessions. In this sentence, replacing "although" by "but" yields nonsense.

Comment: @LPH You're right. I have omitted the reference from my answer. Thanks!